# Can I make a dynamic wallpaper?

Tags: graphics, ios

I'd love to make my own dynamic wallpaper.

Has anybody investigated their format, and if there is a way of making one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/hamzasood/AnimatedWallpaperTest

This is a sample project showing how to make something like a dynamic background but I think you need to jailbreak your phone to make use of it.